# How to Encrypt with Java Decrypt with PHP?

Tags: java, php, encryption

I have a legacy script that has already been saving encrypted data into a database.

The encrypt/decrypt was being done with Java the following code.

```
public class StringEncrypter {

    Cipher ecipher;
    Cipher dcipher;

    /**
     * Constructor used to create this object. Responsible for setting and
     * initializing this object's encrypter and decrypter Chipher instances
     * given a Pass Phrase and algorithm.
     * 
     * @param passPhrase
     *            Pass Phrase used to initialize both the encrypter and
     *            decrypter instances.
     */
    public StringEncrypter(String passPhrase) {

        // 8-bytes Salt
        byte[] salt = { (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
                (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x34, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03 };

        // Iteration count
        int iterationCount = 19;

        try {

            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt,
                    iterationCount);
            SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES")
                    .generateSecret(keySpec);

            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

            // Prepare the parameters to the cipthers
            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt,
                    iterationCount);

            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException");
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeySpecException");
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchPaddingException");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchAlgorithmException");
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeyException");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Takes a single String as an argument and returns an Encrypted version of
     * that String.
     * 
     * @param str
     *            String to be encrypted
     * @return <code>String</code> Encrypted version of the provided String
     */
    public String encrypt(String str) {
        try {
            // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
            byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

            // Encrypt
            byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

            // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Takes a encrypted String as an argument, decrypts and returns the
     * decrypted String.
     * 
     * @param str
     *            Encrypted String to be decrypted
     * @return <code>String</code> Decrypted version of the provided String
     */
    public String decrypt(String str) {

        try {

            // Decode base64 to get bytes
            byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);

            // Decrypt
            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

            // Decode using utf-8
            return new String(utf8, "UTF8");

        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This puts a string into the database like this `RX0qxgKAKmjQmS9xjNtFnw==`

I need to be able to decrypt this data using PHP.

I have tried using this script from github:
https://github.com/KevinBusse/PBEWithMD5AndDES

But can only get an output of `bad magic number`

Is this possible? If so any direction would be greatfully appreciated!

Comment: What is this `Cipher ` class you're using? If it's not coming from a public library, you may need to implement it yourselves in PHP.

Comment: @SachithDickwella - Looks like its coming from a public library. `import javax.crypto.Cipher;`

Comment: Repository moved to https://github.com/kevinsandow/PBEWithMD5AndDES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Github-code can be used for decryption if the following settings are taken from the Java-code:

- Salt (hex): `A99BC8325634E303`
- Iterations: `19`

Example:

```
Passphrase:                    MyPassphraseXYZ
Plaintext:                     The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Ciphertext from the Java code: xWnsqJJ4pqWTrm8kIwfyw1djD4lu0zig0wnohS+EtwDvHBgEP/BS25qyaE+QEdxd
```

The ciphertext can be decrypted with the PHP-code as follows:

```
$data = "xWnsqJJ4pqWTrm8kIwfyw1djD4lu0zig0wnohS+EtwDvHBgEP/BS25qyaE+QEdxd";
$keystring = "MyPassphraseXYZ";
$salt = "A99BC8325634E303";
$iterationsMd5 = 19; 
$decrypted = PbeWithMd5AndDes::decrypt($data, $keystring, $salt, $iterationsMd5);
print($decrypted . "\n");
```

The following must be taken into account: `PbeWithMd5AndDes` is outdated and that already for years, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/24594). The Github-code itself uses other deprecated functions such as [`mcrypt_module_XXX()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-module-open.php) and [`mcrypt_generic_YYY()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic-init.php), so that this code can only be executed with PHP < 7.2. In PHP 7.1, deprecated-warnings are displayed. Only for PHP < 7.1 the code can be executed without warnings. All in all, algorithm and code are insecure.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed to do. Thanks!